# Place a input text (form) over an image

Tags: html, css

I would like to design a web page with the input text control (form) that is placed over the image according to specified position, I tried CSS with all the properties for position and when I adjust the size of the window or open with different resolution, they are not in the correct positions anymore, could you please help me what to do to fix that ? Thanks

[Link of the image (example like this)](http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/5NhDny.png)

Comment: What did you tried? any code?

Comment: Without the thing that is to fix, we cannot fix it!

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want ?

http://jsbin.com/emecun/1/edit

Code available at above url.

Answer (score 0):

Use the image as a background-image for a div and put your form in this div. Set the width and the height of the div and then it shouldn't resize.

Something like this:

```
div{
    background-image: url('image.gif') no-repeat;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but when I set the div left, right and top for my form controls, whenever I resize a window, their positions are incorrect!

Comment: Try setting the form position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it in the background. If u want to align it, the way u did in the image. Then use a table for it. And keep images in the background of the cell
Thats what we can say till you provide any further information.